# Access Query for Positive Checkboxes

Tags: microsoft-access, query

I have a table which contains personal information of our staff, at the end of the table there are checkboxes for general training (medical, military, health and safety) etc.

Say for example i wanted to find staff with military experience, I want to be able to create a query that goes through all employees and only shows the entries that have a tick on the military training checkbox.

My access is a little rusty and reading through other forums all questions relevant to this are much more complicated than mine, or involve VBA.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Access in front of me right now, but if memory serves, you should be able to:

1. Open your query in Design View
2. Select your Table/Field
3. In the Criteria row of the field, enter **True** (equates to a check in the Check Box)
4. Save and run your query to confirm the results.